# How to find online Twilio Clients at any point of time?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I have scenarios where different web applications use same Twilio account to create capability token and then initialize/setup Device JS SDK in browser using it.

[EDIT]

This is how a client device is registered using some unique identity/name : [Example code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/incoming-calls)

[/EDIT]

At any instant many such browser based web clients can be live and I would like to know which all clients/identities are live with valid(unexpired) token so that I can decide which client/identity can take incoming calls, using some algorithm.

Is there a Twilio API which I can query to get valid online clients/identities at any point of time?

*PS*: I am not looking for list of Authorized connect Apps or sub-accounts.

Comment: I don't believe there is an API for that. You could look into using [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter) to connect active clients to workers and distribute tasks using [workflows](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workflow-configuration) though.